# Why I got weird Output with a nested list in python

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I just wanted to create a nested loop of names and score which are taken by input, but I am getting a rather weird output.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcPPB.png) to get the image of my code and output. As you can see I am getting both the list from the 3rd and 4th input. Please tell me, why 1st and 2nd inputs are getting overwritten.

Here is my code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    name = input()
    score = float(input()) 
    record = []
    
    while True:
        report = []
        report.append(name)
        report.append(score) 
        record.append(report)
        
        if len(record) == n:
            break       

print(record)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the text of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your `record` and `report` variables in the wrong places:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    record = []
    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
        name = input()
        score = float(input()) 

        report = []
        report.append(name)
        report.append(score) 
        record.append(report)
                
    print(record)
```

The `while` loop was redundant as the `for` loop does everything you need in terms of looping.

Your code would be better if you added strings to your input to give the user a prompt. (This would not be needed if the input is automated)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but

```
record = []
```

is defined in the loop. On running through the loop, it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop doesn't really make any sense. Simply grab your inputs and add them to your list. Record needs to be defined outside of your loops otherwise it'll get overwritten on every iteration.

```
record = []    
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
  name = input()
  score = float(input()) 
  record.append(name)
  record.append(score) 
print(record)
```

Comment: Thank you! As you can see I am a novice. Anyways thanks for you suggestion